Ubuntu 24.10 Wifi Connection Issues
I recently updated to 24.10 from 24.04, and it has caused all sorts of WiFi connection issues. Originally, I could get the WiFi working again if I used rfkill unblock all, but that is no longer the case. Now it just asks continuously to authenticate the WiFi, which I will keep doing, but nothing happens until it does. It is honestly random as to how and when it will connect. However, it will be fine once connected.
I have looked everywhere to fix this solution, and I have found and run these commands:
$ lshw -C network

*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 74:4c:a1:71:00:53
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=6.11.0-9-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.75 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


$ nmcli general

STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN     METERED      
connected  full          enabled  enabled  missing  enabled  no (guessed)

Someone suggested running journalctl -b -0 and reporting the findings, but after 5000 lines, I just kind of gave up as I did not know what I am looking for.

Can you try it?
sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager


Here is the response I got in terminal:  rm: cannot remove '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*': No such file or directory
